# Remove parameters from URL

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess, url-rewriting, rewrite

I need remove a parameter from urls with htaccess

from

```
1) http://example.com/?id=126:&catid=89
2) http://example.com/page?id=126:&catid=89
```

to

```
1) http://example.com/
2) http://example.com/page
```

I am using this htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page?id=126:&catid=89$
RewriteRule ^page$ /page? [L,R=301]
```

This doesn't remove the parameter tho

Comment: Do you have this directive first? `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Yeah :)  I have several other directives that are working fine - this has been placed above all other directives.